# pass and access arguments inside a class in python uising *args

Tags: python

I have a class where i am passing variables inside **init** function using *args.
These arguments has to be user, url and user_key and i have to do some input validations on the arguments passed

```
def __init__(self, *args):
    """init method for the class."""
    print args
    if args[0] is not None:
        self.user = user
        print(self.user)
    if args[1] is not None:
        self.url = url
        print(self.url)
    if args[2] is not None:
        self.user_key = user_key
        print(self.user_key)
```

But these values are not getting printed when i try to print them.
Is there any other way to access these variables?
i am getting the below error

```
    self.user = user
NameError: global name 'user' is not defined
```

Comment: if you already know how many arguments there are and what they should represent why use `*args` at all? You could just assign default `None` value

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the check on None you are printing them, you should check instead that the valuse are **not** equal to None, also you are printing undefinned variable `user`, instead assign the `self.user` to `args[index]`:

Also you should add try and catch in case no arguments were provided:

```
def __init__(self, *args):
    """init method for the class."""
    print args
    try:
        if args[0] is not None:
           self.user = args[0]
           print(self.user)
    except IndexError:
        print('No arguments  provided')
```

Comment: @poobear you should pass the value in args[0]

Answer (score 0):

if you need to pass keyword arguments to the function, use arguments like `**kwargs` instead, then all the keyword arguments passed to the function, and which is not caught by named keyword arguments, will be stored in a dict named `kwargs`. so if you need to visit argument `user`, just use `kwargs['user']` instead.

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    """init method for the class."""
    print(kwargs)
    if 'user' in kwargs:
        self.user = kwargs['user']
        print(self.user)
    if 'urlin' kwargs:
        self.url = kwargs['url']
        print(self.url)
    if 'user_keyin' kwargs:
        self.user_key = kwargs['user_key']
        print(self.user_key)
```

Comment: if user in kwargs:
NameError: global name 'user' is not defined
this is the error i get